# What is the difference among ios::app, out, and trunc in c++?

Tags: c++

I know that the default file open mode is **out**. And I think **out** will overwrite the data in the file, but in the following code, it **age data** doesn’t overwrite **name data**.

```
#include <fstream> 
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std;

int main () {

    char data[100];

    // open a file in write mode.
    ofstream outfile;
    outfile.open("afile.dat");

    cout << "Writing to the file" << endl; 
    cout << "Enter your name: ";
    cin.getline(data, 100);

    // write inputted data into the file.
    outfile << data << endl;

    cout << "Enter your age: "; 
    cin >> data; 
    cin.ignore();

    // again write inputted data into the file.
    outfile << data << endl;
    // close the opened file.
    outfile.close();

    // open a file in read mode.
    ifstream infile; 
    infile.open("afile.dat");

    cout << "Reading from the file" << endl; 
    infile >> data;

    // write the data at the screen. 
    cout << data << endl;

    // again read the data from the file and display it. 
    infile >> data; 
    cout << data << endl;

    // close the opened file.
    infile.close();

    return 0;
```

Then I’m confused about the three open mode for file – app, out, trunc.

If for name I enter “Zara” and age “9”, the output should be “9ara”. However, it is not. It is “Zara 9”.

Answer (score 21):

`ios::out` is the default mode for `std::ofstream`, it means that output operations can be used (i.e. you can write to the file).

`ios::app` (short for *append*) means that instead of overwriting the file from the beginning, all output operations are done at the end of the file. This is only meaningful if the file is also open for output.

`ios::trunc` (short for *truncate*) means that when the file is opened, the old contents are immediately removed. Again, this is only meaningful if the file is also open for output.

Your code just uses the default `ios::out` mode. So it starts writing from the beginning of the file, but doesn't remove the old contents. So the new contents will overlay what's already there -- if the file is originally 10 bytes long, and you write 3 bytes, the result will be the 3 bytes you write followed by the remaining 7 bytes of the original contents. More concretely, if the file originally contains:

```
Firstname Lastname
30
```

and you write `FN LN` and then `20` (with newlines after each), the resulting file will look like:

```
FN LN
20
 Lastname
30
```

because you only overwrite the first 9 bytes of the file (assuming Unix-style newlines).

Once you've opened the file, all outputs to the file are written sequentially after each other, unless you use `outfile.seekp()` to go to a different location. It doesn't go back to the beginning of the file for each thing you write. `seekp()` has no effect if the `ios::app` is used; then every write goes at the end of the file.

Comment: Got it. But I still don’t understand the output of above code. Actually it’s in this tutorial:[enter link description here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_files_streams.htm). Why doesn’t age overwrite name from the beginning?

Comment: Please update the question, showing the output you're expecting and what you're getting instead.

Comment: When you do `infile >> data` it will only read one word from the file. So if you entered a firstname and lastname, it will just read the firstname. Use `infile.getline()` to read a whole line from the file.

Comment: I've updated the answer. It only goes to the beginning when the file is first opened, not between each output operation.

Comment: You are mistaken: If the you open the file in a write mode but you didn't specify std::ios::trunc or std::app then by default std::ios::trunc is specified which means the content is truncated and the new data if any will be placed from the beginning on.

Answer (score 7):

Just a little correction to Barmar's answer. I think that the type ofstream implies not only the ios::out, but also the ios::trunc (and I'm not sure, but the ios::out could also imply the ios::trunc).

Here's the concrete example:

```
ofstream fich;
    fich.open("archivo.txt");
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < ag.n_pers && !fich.fail(); ++i) {
        escribir_persona(fich, ag.pers[i]);
    }
    if (fich.fail()) {
        ok = ERROR;
    }
    else {
        ok = OK;
    }
    fich.close();
```

When I call this function, the data of the file is completely overwrited (even if the data to write is less than that which was writen previously), and if the data to write is empty, this just deletes everything in the file.

Comment: AFAIK The difference between ios::out and ios::trunc is when reading (and writing) from the file, i.e. when using fstream, not ofstream. @Barmer's answer is correct for fstream, but the question is about ofstream, so he is wrong here. This is the correct answer.